# Call multiple async methods to eventually return one string value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have a synchronous method that processes a custom value by calling multiple methods to modify the string value we want to return, see below:

```
public string ProcessCustomValue(string value, DataRow row)
    {
        string customValue = value;

        customValue = Method1(customValue, row);
        customValue = Method2(customValue, row);
        customValue = Method3(customValue, row);
        customValue = Method4(customValue);
        customValue = Method5(customValue, row);

        return customValue;
    }
```

At a glance this is not a nice way of calling these methods and is expensive to perform synchronously. Each MethodX performs a series of string replacements in between some basic logic. There is no expectation for Method1 to finish before Method2 is called etc.

How can I perform these calls asynchronously (if possible) to return value as portrayed above?

Comment: `There is no expectation for Method1 to finish before Method2 is called etc.` - so why do you call `Method1()` or other?

Comment: If these methods aren't expected to be performed in order, why do they all accept and return the same variable?  Doesn't that make the result of this method non-deterministic?  What do these methods actually do?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? It matters.String manipulations don't need asynchronous processing. If you want to perform them in the background, you could just use `Task.Run(()=>ProcessCustomValue(someString,someRow))`. If you wanted to process a lot of rows though, you'd probably use `Parallel.ForEach`, or PLINQ

Comment: @David each method repeatedly calls string.Replace() in some basic logic, upon further inspection of this old code a string is supplied i.e. `[Time:SomeValue] [ParentNC:AnotherValue] [ParentNC:AndAnotherValue] `

Where each seperate container "[Time:...]" is formatted in a respective method.

Comment: @defrrdClock: Which continues to imply that they need to run deterministically.  If Y depends on the result of X, then how can you expect to do Y before X is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to enable parallelism so that those methods can be invoked in parallel. This is not possible here since each method requires the previous method's output.